# If else statement between two combobox using c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

I implemented two Combobox in my coding. 1st combobox contain the city name and the 2nd combobox contain the POI of that city. Now I want to implement if else statement between this two combobox. Suppose if I select 1st combobox, Button will enable only for 1st one, then if I select 2nd Combobox then Button will work for 2nd one. I do not know how to do it. My code is like this

```
public void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // if combox1 select
   // all function will work for combobox 1

   //else if combobox2 select
   //combobbox1 disabled and all function will work for combobx2    
}
```

Initially I created class to set the value of combobox1 like this

```
            class PlaceList
                {

                    public static ComboBox Combo_list = new ComboBox();
                    public static DataGridView dataTable = new DataGridView();

                    public static void List()
                    {

                        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
                        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
                        string SavedfileName = "POI_list.json";
                        var Saving_path = Path.Combine(folderName, SavedfileName);

                        string fileName = "Zensus_Gemeinden_org.xlsx";
                        var path = Path.Combine(startPath, fileName);

                        String name = "Gemeinden_31.12.2011_Vergleich";
                        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                       path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select [3] as City,[4] as Population, * From [" + name + "$D7:E11300] Where [4] > 10000", con);
                        con.Open();

                        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                        DataTable data = new DataTable();

                        sda.Fill(data);
                        dataTable.DataSource = data;



                        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Combo_list.Items.Add(data.Rows[i]["City"]);
                        }


                        string Place_Json = "Place_List:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
                        File.WriteAllText(Saving_path, Place_Json);

                    }
                }
   }
```

Then in Form1.cs I created

```
   Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();


    private void LoadKeys()
    {

       foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("TextFile1.txt"))
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());
                    poi[parts[0]] = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));
                }

    }

    void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string txt = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (poi.ContainsKey(txt))
            {
                List<string> points = poi[txt];
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

That means combobox2 is dependent of combobox1. It will give the places name accoerding to the combobox1

then finally in form1.cs button 1 I am trying to do this somethis like this

```
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        PlaceList.Combo_list = comboBox1;
        PlaceList.List();
        LoadKeys();


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            ShortText.txt1 = richTextBox1;
            ShortText.shortText(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            ShortText.txt1 = richTextBox1;
            ShortText.shortText(comboBox2.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

Comment: Is it the same button for both combo boxes, or two different buttons?

Comment: `if (sender == comboBox1) { } else { }` ?

Comment: Different event for each combobox?

Comment: Checking the sender won't work, it will be the button.  It sounds like you're trying to share the button between each combo box, why not check each combo box to see if the combo box is enabled and/or set to the default index to see which the user has changed?

Comment: what if you select both the Combobox?

Comment: @ScoobyDrew18: I use one button for two combobox. I am trying if I select city from combobox1 it will show all function for that. If I select combox that means poi then all function is set for that. Right now in my code I implement two different button for two combobox. But it would be better if I use one

Comment: @Graham: Same function but combobox item is different. That is why I want to make a if else between two combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Check the selected index of each combobox for the default value.  The one that isn't the default value is the one you use.  For example, if the default is index 0:

```
if(combo1.SelectedIndex != 0){
    //do something
}
else if(combo2.SelectedIndex != 0) {
    //do something else
}
else {
    // Error: You need to select something!
}
```

Comment: No it i not not working it always shows the first combobox value

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. Please check now. @ScoobyDrew

Comment: What is the default index of each combo box?

Comment: Sorry.I cannot understand clearly.for combobox1 is City and Combobox 2 is the POI.